# Switch button doesnt work with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm using a switch button in my app to turn music on/off. I'm using SharedPreferences to save the last state of my switch button. But when i go out of my app and run again it gives me "off" state as a default all time. I want to save the state of user's choice all time even when they close and run app again. Here is my code `public class SettingsView extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Switch musicSwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    musicSwitch = findViewById(R.id.sLLmusicSwitch);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    musicSwitch.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("value", true));
    switchCheckListener();
}

private void switchCheckListener() {
    musicSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (musicSwitch.isChecked()) {
                // saving state of the switch button
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.apply();
                musicSwitch.setChecked(true);
                // turn on music
                Repository.getInstance().startMusic();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // saving state of the switch button
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.apply();
                musicSwitch.setChecked(false);
                //turn off music
                Repository.getInstance().pauseMusic();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving your boolean state to shared preferences under they key `NameOfThingToSave`, and retrieveing it on onCreate with key `value`.

in onCreate set the key value appropriately:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    musicSwitch = findViewById(R.id.sLLmusicSwitch);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("save",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    switchCheckListener();

    musicSwitch.setChecked(sharedpreferences.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false));
}
```

Comment: Thanks the state of the switch works now but the music is still off every time I close and run the app again. Any ideas why?

Comment: Call ```switchCheckListener();``` before ```setChecked```.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now but I have a little problem left. When I leave the state of music "on" and close the app and run it again, music is not starting until I go inside the settings activity. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to call this ```Repository.getInstance().startMusic();``` when your app starts, in whatever activity that is and check preferences if music is enabled.